# How do I use socket.io from a server at a subfolder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've been following the tutorial at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/, and I have the following 2 files:

`app.js`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname});
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');

    //Send a message after a timeout of 4 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        socket.send('Sent a message 4 seconds after connection!');
    }, 4000);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>
    <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('message', function(data){document.write(data)});
    </script>
    <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

If I run this in Node.js version 10.16.3 and visit `http://localhost/`, everything works fine. The server console logs:

```
A user connected
```

And the browser eventually displays:

```
Sent a message 4 seconds after connection!
```

So far, so good!

The problems arise when I try to run this from my website. Let's pretend it's called `example.com`.
My web hosting provider uses the same version of Node.js, and has set it up so that each Node.js application runs in a subfolder. Let's pretend it's called `example.com/x`.

When visiting `http://example.com/x`, the browser displays:

```
Cannot GET /x/
```

So in `app.js`, I changed this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname});
});
```

...to this:

```
app.get('/x', function(req, res) {
    // Redirect if no slash at the end
    if (!req.url.endsWith('/')) {
        res.redirect(301, req.url + '/')
    }
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname});
});
```

Now the initial page loads, but the browser console logs:

```
The resource from “http://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js”.
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Obviously, my app doesn't get a chance to handle this request because it's addressed to the main domain.

So I changed both files:
In `app.js`, I changed this line:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

to this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: "/x/socket.io"});
```

And in `index.html`, I changed this line:

```
    <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
    <script src = "/x/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This got rid of the errors in the browser console, but it still doesn't seem to be connecting.

The browser never displays:

```
Sent a message 4 seconds after connection!
```

Same when I run all this in `http://localhost/x/`, and the Node.js console never logs:

```
A user connected
```

Is there an easier way to go about all this than the changes I've been making so far?
If not, what more do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One step left.

In `index.html`, change this line:

```
        var socket = io();
```

...to this:

```
        var socket = io.connect("/", {path: "/x/socket.io"});
```

This should work for both `http://example.com/x` and `http://localhost/x`.